# ThymeLeaf not printing values of List

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following html:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Sightings</title>
  </head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
                <div class="row m-4">
                <div class="col text-center border border-dark">
                    <h1><a href="/" class="text-dark">Sightings Manager</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="heroes" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Heroes</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Organizations</a>
                </div>

                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="locations" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Locations</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <a href="sightings" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Sightings</a>

                </div>
               
                
            </div>
              <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
               <div class="col text-left border border-dark">
              <input type="radio" id="selectByDate" name="selectOption" value="selectByDate">
              <label for="selectByDate">Sightings By Date</label><br>

              <input type="radio" id="selectByHero" name="selectOption" value="selectByHero">
              <label for="selectByHero">Sightings by Hero</label>

              
              <div class="col text-center" id="date" style="display:none;">
              <form action="getLocationsByDate" method="GET">
              <select id="chooseDate" name="chooseDate">
              <option selected disabled>Choose a date</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="View Locations">
              </form>
              </div>
              <!-- Other div to go here with other form -->
              </div>
            </div>
              
            <div class="row m-4 border border-dark">
                <div class="col text-center m-3">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Latitude</th>
                                <th>Longitude</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="location : ${locations}">
                                <td th:text="${location.id}">Location ID</td>
                                <td th:text='${location.name}'>Location Name</td>
                                <td th:text="${location.address}">Location Address</td>
                                <td th:text="${location.latitude}">Location Latitude</td>
                                <td th:text="${location.longitude}">Location Longitude</td>

                                
          
                             
                            </tr>
    
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            
            
            </div>
            
            
            
            </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="sightings.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As well as the following javascript:

```html
$(document).ready(selectOption);

function selectOption()
{
    $('input:radio[name="selectOption"]').change(function()
                                        {
                                            if($(this).val() == "selectByDate")
                                            {
                                                $("#date").show();
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type:"GET",
                                                    url:"http://localhost:8080/getDates",
                                                    success: function(dates)
                                                    {
                                                        console.log(dates.length);
                                                        for(let i=0;i<dates.length;i++)
                                                        {
                                                                    optionText=dates[i];
                                                                    optionValue=dates[i];
                                                                    $("#chooseDate").append(new Option(optionText,optionValue));
                                                        }
                                                        //if viewlocations has been clicked
                                        
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    
                                                });
                                                
                                                
                                            }
                                            else if($(this).val() == "selectByHero")
                                            {
                                                $('#chooseDate')
                                                    .empty()
                                                    .append('<option selected disabled>Choose a date</option>'); //remove all data as will stack on top of each other
                                                $("#date").hide();
                                            }
                                        });
}
```

Both are run via a controller in spring mvc:

```
@Controller
public class SightingsController 
{
@Autowired
HeroDAO heroDao;

@Autowired
LocationDao locationDao;


@GetMapping("sightings")
public String displayLocations()
{
    return "sightings";
    
}
@GetMapping(value="getDates",produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<LocalDate> getDates()//returns all dates of herosightings and adds it to model
{
    List<Sighting> sightings = locationDao.getAllSightings();
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    
    for(int i=0;i<sightings.size();i++)
    {
        dates.add(sightings.get(i).getDate());
    }
    return dates;
}
@GetMapping("getLocationsByDate")
public String getLocationsByDate(HttpServletRequest request,Model model)
{
    String date =request.getParameter("chooseDate");
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    List<Location> locations = locationDao.sightingsOnDate(localDate);
    model.addAttribute("locations",locations);
    return "redirect:/sightings";
    
}
```

My javascript acts to populate a selection box by using an ajax call to the controllers public List getDates() which returns a list of dates and adds it to the html . The user then selects one of these items and submits it to the controller again to public String getLocationsByDate(HttpServletRequest request,Model model). This function is supposed to add a model to the bottom of the page(in the tbody) and print out all the results. My problem is the thymeleaf seems to not be reading the values at all(nothng appears in tbody). I do know the values submitted to /getLocationsByDate and the values received by         List locations=locationDao.sightingsOnDate(localDate); are correct, however doing the .addAttribute seems to be nothing on the html page. Any help would be appreciated and I do hope it is not some syntax error.

Edit: Also if need to see what is in the  Location object:

```
public class Location 
{
private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private String address;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}
public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}
public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((latitude == null) ? 0 : latitude.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((longitude == null) ? 0 : longitude.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Location other = (Location) obj;
    if (address == null) {
        if (other.address != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
        return false;
    if (description == null) {
        if (other.description != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
        return false;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (latitude == null) {
        if (other.latitude != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!latitude.equals(other.latitude))
        return false;
    if (longitude == null) {
        if (other.longitude != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!longitude.equals(other.longitude))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}



}
```

Comment: Nevermind I solved the issue but I am not sure really why this caused the issue. I just returned the html instead of redirecting it in the controller

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own question if you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue(although I am not sure why the solution works.. will need to do further research). I returned the html in the controller rather than using a redirect. This seemed to be what was causing the problem.